# Take date from HTML5 form - and Post to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, date

I've got a basic web form, and I need to take a date from a "date" type input (html5 see http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date) and post it into my MySQL database (which has a type of DATE - note: not DATETIME).

I need some kind of PHP/JS voodoo to make the 2 talk to each other, Any clues?

Heres what I've got so far, and it always produces the default date of 1970-01-01.

Would it be better to do it as a plain input and force the format with Jquery?

```
<!-- zee form: -->
<div>
    <!-- Start Date -->
    <div>
        <label class="col-offset-half col-3" for="order_contractStart">Contract Start:</label>
        <input class="col-offset-half col-7" type="date" id="order_contractStart" name="order_contractStart">
    </div>
    <!-- End Date -->
    <div>
        <label class="col-offset-half col-3" for="order_contractEnd">Contract End:</label>
        <input class="col-offset-half col-7" type="date" id="order_contractEnd" name="order_contractEnd">
    </div>
```

Then in my action I have:

```
//Get Variables from form
$start = date("Y-m-d", $_GET['order_start']);
$end = date("Y-m-d", $_GET['order_end']);
```

Turns out this method isn't really working - so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are using "order_contractStart" in the name attribute, make sure you use the same in php, $_GET['order_contractStart']. You also need a form tag around the input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `strtotime()` before calling `date()`, so you can work on UNIX timestamps (which are required for date ;). Plus the indexes aren't matching the ones defined in the HTML.

```
$start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET['order_contractStart']));
$end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET['order_contractEnd']));
```

Also don't be [fooled by w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/)!

Comment: So its still a string, I never would have thought. Its working just fine now. I had already changed the indexes - but it was still baffling me. Annoying that I've just found out that html5 date doesn't work in safari.

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
<input type="date" name="DOB">
```

then

```
$DOB = $_POST['DOB'];
```

as if you echo

```
echo $_POST['DOB'] . '<br>';
echo strtotime($_POST['DOB']) . '<br>';
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['DOB'])) . '<br>';
```

you will see that the 1st and 3rd line are the same.
My problem was that I was using Bind SQL, which needs to be

```
$stmt->bind_param('s
```

with an 's'
and also structure for the column in the database set to Date.

Also `<input type="date">` only works for Chrome, Safari and Opera, not Firefox or Internet Explorer.
So I would recommend using something like

```
<input type="date" name="DOB" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" pattern="\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}">
```

for it to work on all browsers and for validation

Answer (score 0):

this is finish

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- zee form: -->
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<div>
    <!-- Start Date -->
    <div>
        <label class="col-offset-half col-3" for="order_contractStart">Contract Start:</label>
        <input class="col-offset-half col-7" type="date" id="order_contractStart" name="order_contractStart">
    </div>
    <!-- End Date -->
    <div>
        <label class="col-offset-half col-3" for="order_contractEnd">Contract End:</label>
        <input class="col-offset-half col-7" type="date" id="order_contractEnd" name="order_contractEnd">
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit"></div>

</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$start =  $_POST['order_contractStart'];
$end = $_POST['order_contractEnd'];
echo $start;
echo "<br>";
echo $end;

}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? PLease add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it